# Using ngInx with react js

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I am new to the react js. I am trying to use nginx config,

so here is my file

**nginx.conf**

```
# auto detects a good number of processes to run
worker_processes auto;

#Provides the configuration file context in which the directives that affect connection processing are specified.
events {
    # Sets the maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process.
    worker_connections 8000;
    # Tells the worker to accept multiple connections at a time
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    # what times to include
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # what is the default one
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Sets the path, format, and configuration for a buffered log write
    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $upstream_addr '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    server {
        # listen on port 80
        listen 80;
        # save logs here
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;

        # where the root here
        root /var/www;
        # what file to server as index
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to redirecting to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }



        # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Javascript and CSS files
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
        location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I am hitting the request then also I am getting a 405 error

what I am trying here is I want to make an API call to a server which is running on a different port .
So I tried this way. But now I am not able to do this .

can any one tell me where I need to change ?

Comment: Your current nginx configuration looks for files in `/var/www` for the requests received. If you are running a server at a different port, you need to proxy it accordingly in the `location` block.

Comment: so you mean I have to use    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

Comment: Should I remove the try_files ?

Comment: If it is just a plain react app, it can be hosted by using nginx alone. You just need to build the react app, copy the files to `/var/www`. You need to proxy pass only if the react app is coupled with a backend application which serves the react app on requesting a url.

Comment: yes It is like that. we call some API so we need to have that proxy. But I have not used proxy in package.json is it okay ?

Comment: Is it an external api? Is it served on some other url? if that is the case then, you dont need any proxying. Just build the react app with `yarn build`. Then copy the built files to `/var/www`. Then it should work with your existing nginx configuration.

Comment: Yes, I mean , There is server where I have deployed my back-end services which is running on 8081 . Now I have to deploy the front end on the same server but its running on different port. this application needs some data which is given by backend like api calls. So for this I am using ngInx

Comment: Okay, so you can host the react app in `your-domain.com` and backend api at `api.your-domain.com`. That would require two nginx configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Did you proxy your API url?

```
{
...
,
  "proxy": "localhost_or_url:your_port",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

By the way, remember that you need to run a production version of app thus you can serve it with nginx

Comment: No I have not used that.

Answer (score 1):

Create nginx config for your react app

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_domain.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name your-domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/your-domain.access.log;
    root /var/www;
    # what file to server as index
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to redirecting to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Create nginx config for your backend api

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/api.your_domain.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.your-domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.your-domain.access.log;
    root /var/www;
    # what file to server as index
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
    }
}
```

Create symlinks to enable the apps.

`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_domain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/api.your_domain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

check for errors.

`nginx -t`

restart nginx

`sudo service nginx restart`

Copy the react build files to `/var/www` (It should have an index.html file)

Make sure to run your backend at port 8081.

Make the Api calls from react app to `api.your-domain.com`