# Error while starting a react app via `npm start` in `Vultr`

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, vultr

While starting a react app via `npm start` in `Vultr` I am getting below an error :
Could anyone please advise what is causing this error. I am not getting the error in my local system.

root@automateandmore:~/automatemore# npm start

> vinmatblogs@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

```
Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **build** a React project and publish it with Nginx directly on a Vultr VPS. So you don't need to run any nodejs server.

For this, you need to specify the path of the build file created with the `npm build` command in the nginx configuration.

As for your question, if for some reason you want to publish your site in development mode by running nodejs server with the `npm start` command; you can add the following to the package.json file.

```
"devServer": {
     "allowedHosts": "all"
   }
```

With this code, you allow the running nodejs server to be accessed from any device. Don't forget to run it again with `npm start` after making this addition.

I also recommend to read this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505427/14893142

Comment: How can I access the nginx configuration and  `specify the path of the build file created with the npm build command in the nginx configuration` as you mentioned

Comment: @soccerway It depends. One way is that you'll create a file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ directory. Put some info in that file with the path of your build folder as root statement. Then you'll link that file to /etc/sites-enabled/ folder. Then you'll restart nginx server. Here are some links for detailed information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52714450/14893142  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713902/using-nginx-with-react-js https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dIVesHEAzc